# consultar arquivos da tabela pelo dia, entre dois meses

Tags: php, sql, data

Gostaria de ter apoio para um problema que estou passando no momento.

tenho que retornar valores de uma consulta a partir dos dias de um mes onde pode começar no dia 01 do mes passado até hoje que seria 02.

exemplo: 01/05/2022 ate 02/06/2022

ja consigo ler os arquivos durante o mes vigente a partir de um FOR

```php
for($i = 25; $i < 32; $i++){
     
     if($i<10) $i = "0".$i;
     $x_00   = $mysqli->query("SELECT horario FROM horarios WHERE valor = 0 and TIME(horario) BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '01:00:00' AND data like '%2022-05-".$i."%' ");
     $cont_00 = $x_00->num_rows;
     
     if($cont_00 != 0 ){
         echo "Horario 00 : ".$cont_00."<br>";
    }
     
     $x_01 = $mysqli->query("SELECT horario FROM horarios WHERE valor = 0 and TIME(horario) BETWEEN '01:00:00' AND '02:00:00' AND '01:00:00' AND data like '%2022-05-".$i."%' ");
     $cont_01 = $x_01->num_rows;
     
    if($cont_01 != 0 ){
         echo "Horario 01 : ".$cont_01."<br>";
    }
    $x_02   = $mysqli->query("SELECT horario FROM horarios WHERE valor = 0 and TIME(horario) BETWEEN '02:00:00' AND '03:00:00' AND '01:00:00' AND data like '%2022-05-".$i."%' ");
    $cont_02 = $x_02->num_rows;
     
    if($cont_02 != 0 ){
        echo "Horario 02 : ".$cont_02."<br>";
    }
}
```

No entanto a partir de ontem começou este problema no sistema porque o mes mudou e nao tenho ideia de como poderia criar esta logica.

Alguem já fez este tipo de trabalho para me ajudar por favor.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Usa `GROUP BY` com `COUNT` e passa como parâmetros a data inicial e a data final. O `GROUP BY` vai agrupar por horários e o `COUNT` vai contar as vezes que o horário aparece.

```
Select horario, count(horario)
from   horaio
where  valor = 0 
and    data_inicial BETWEEN 'data_final
group by horario
```

Comment: Legal cara me ajudou muito nisso aqui, só vou precisar agora especificar o intervalo de horario pra finalizar.

pois preciso da faixa separada 

exemplo: 00:00 as 01:00 ... consegui ajustar ai, tentei aqui e to con dificuldade

Answer (score -3):

Consegui utilizando a função TIME para inddicar o intervalo de horario, OBRIGADO

> Select horario, count(horario) from   horarios where  valor = '0'
>
> and data BETWEEN '2022-05-01' AND '2022-06-02'  and time(data) BETWEEN
> '01:00' and '02:00' group by horario